# handling a POST request

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to POST some data but I am not achieving what I need to.

No matter what `list-item` I click on, it is POSTing the value of the top most `list-item`.

this is the jquery function:

```
$(".list-item-wrap a").click(function(){
    $.post("display2.php", { 
        msg_id: $(".list-item-wrap a .list-item").find('input').val()},
        function(data) {
            $("#list").load("display2.php", {
                msg_id: $(".list-item-wrap a .list-item").find('input').val()
            });
        //window.location.replace("display2.php");
    })
})
```

This is the actual html/php data:

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT * from workflow WHERE name = '$username' ORDER BY msg_id DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("ERROR: $query.".mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    echo "<div class=list-item-wrap>";
    echo "<a href='#'><div class=list-item><input class=msgid type=hidden value="
              .$row->msg_id.">";
    echo "<b><h1>".$row->subject."</h1></b>".substr($row->message, 0, 200)
              ."...<br><b>".$row->sender."</b>";
    echo "</div></a></div>";
}
?>
```

Where am I going wrong??

Answer (score 2):

When you call `val()` on a set of elements, it will only return the value of the 1st one.  You need to call `val()` on just the element you want.

Try using this instead, to get the item you clicked on:

```
$(".list-item input", this).val()
```

In this case, `this` is the `.list-item-wrap a` you want, so you need to get the `input` after it.

Or, if you want to post ALL of the items, use this:

```
$('input', '.list-item-wrap a .list-item').serialize()
```

Answer (score 1):

you need a preventDefault() on the anchor click:

```
$(".list-item-wrap a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("display2.php", {msg_id: $(".list-item-wrap a .list-item").find('input').val()},
    function(data){
        $("#list").load("display2.php", {msg_id: $(".list-item-wrap a .list-item").find('input').val()});
        //window.location.replace("display2.php");
    })
})
```

Comment: or return false; at the end. Does the same thing

Comment: I downvoted because this wasn't the issue here.  I've removed it though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `return false` at the end of the function. Like:

```
$(".list-item-wrap a").click(function(){
    $.post("display2.php", {msg_id: $(".list-item-wrap a .list-item").find('input').val()},
    function(data){
        $("#list").load("display2.php", {msg_id: $(".list-item-wrap a .list-item").find('input').val()});
        //window.location.replace("display2.php");
    })
    return false;
})
```

Comment: Try changing your `msg_id` variable in the post request to `this.children('.msgid')[0].val()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I misunderstood try this:

```
$(".list-item-wrap a").click(function(){
    $.post("display2.php", {msg_id: $(this).find('input').val()},
    function(data){
        $("#list").load("display2.php", {msg_id: $(".list-item-wrap a .list-item").find('input').val()});
        //window.location.replace("display2.php");
    })
})
```

Comment: i dont understand..why should i push an array? i only need the value for the current list-item?

Comment: I misunderstood that you were looking for the most recent (stupid reading comprehension). Try finding the input off of $(this) instead. The way before was looking for all the inputs and grabbing the value of the first one it saw.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the value of the input element you want..
so limit you selector with

```
msg_id: $("input",this).val()
```

You should also change your callback method to just display the data instead of doing a new ajax call..

```
function(data) {
            $("#list").html(data);
}
```